# How to use mitmdump to translate http2 to local http?

Tags: mitmproxy

I want to use `curl http://127.0.0.1:8033/api/v1` to access https://http2.pro/api/v1 with HTTP/2

This API url will return whether the client using http2.

I have tried: (I'm using latest version 5.0.1)

```
./mitmdump -p 8033 --http2 --set http2_priority=true --mode reverse:https://http2.pro:443
```

However `curl 127.0.0.1:8033/api/v1` still gives:

```
{"http2":0,"protocol":"HTTP\/1.1","push":0,"user_agent":"curl\/7.69.1-DEV"}
```

In contrast, `curl https://http2.pro/api/v1 --http2` gives: (this is what I expected)

```
{"http2":1,"protocol":"HTTP\/2.0","push":0,"user_agent":"curl\/7.69.1-DEV"}
```

Answer (score 1):

mitmproxy currently does not support converting between HTTP/1 and HTTP/2. For HTTP/2 to happen, both endpoints need to speak it. It is on our todo list and will hopefully be possible soon (https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/1775).